# A function which takes 2 uniformly distributed variables, and returns a uniform variable

Tags: distributions

**X** ~ uniform(0,1)

I need a deterministic function *fn* that gives:

- *fn*(c,**X**) ~ uniform(0,1)
- *fn*(**X**,c) ~ uniform(0,1)

For any constant c ϵ (0,1)

Comment: What are you asking exactly? Are you looking for code? This doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Can you clarify if this function is actually taking 2 uniform variables? It looks like it is taking a constant and a distribution.

Comment: Square the maximum of the two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be approximately correct for large $K$:
$fn(a,b) = \text{abs}(a-b)*K-\text{floor} (\text{abs}(a-b)*K)$

Comment: +1 This is a clever solution.  It should work for *any* continuous distribution of $X$ for sufficiently large $K$!

Answer (score 4):

Just take the fractional part of $c+X$.

That is, your function is $\operatorname{fn}(a,b):=(a+b) \!\!\!\mod \! 1$.

For any constant $c$, if $X$ is uniform$(0,1)$ then also the fractional part of $c+X$ is uniform$(0,1)$.